# svn: dump format documentation?

Tags: svn

Is the "svnadmin dump" format documented somewhere? I want to record a datastructure containing all the metadata for a svn repository, which is essentially the same stuff in the "dump" file except for the file contents itself.

Seems like the svnkit library would have it, or have a way to obtain this metadata programmatically, but I've been running around the svnkit javadoc for the last hour and can't find a way to get what I need without going through more trouble than just parsing the svnadmin dump file myself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:
[SVN Dump File Format Specification](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/dump-load-format.txt)

Comment: doh! how did I miss finding that?

Comment: I knew the exact phrase to search for and I still had trouble finding it. Its well hidden, lol.

Answer (score 2):

there is a [grammar of the subversion dump file format](http://www.cubewano.org/blacktackle/browser/doc/svn-dumpfile-grammar.txt) at http://www.cubewano.org/blacktackle/wiki/SubversionTools (via http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html). you might also check out the svn-dump2dir and svn-dir2dump (and the other) scripts there.