# SVN load ./myNewRepo < ./myOldRepo.dump -- Can't open file 'myNewRepo/format'?

Tags: svn, version-control, svnadmin, version-control-migration, svndump

I'm trying to migrate an old repository (let's call it `myOldRepo`) to a new repository (`myNewRepo`).

I've got an svndump of the old repo, `myOldRepo.dump`. I've checked out my new repository, `myNewRepo`. Both are in the same directory. I'm trying to use the following command to load the old repo dump into the new repo:

```
svnadmin load ./myNewRepo < ./myOldRepo.svndump
```

This gives the following error:

```
svnadmin: Can't open file 'myNewRepo/format': No such file or directory
```

I've been using SVN for a long time, and I haven't seen a `format` file in any of my repositories. What is this `format` that is expected in myNewRepo?

I also tried creating an empty `format` file (`touch format`) in the myNewRepo directory. Then, when I do the `svnadmin load` command, I get the following:

```
svnadmin: Can't read file 'myNewRepo/format': End of file found
```

I've seen [posts](http://forums.apisnetworks.com/archive/index.php/t-186.html) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598254/svn-create-a-dump-file-of-a-folder) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579432/svn-dump-format-documentation) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852361/svn-load-new-repository) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843534/merging-svn-repositories-i-loaded-old-repository-onto-an-existing-repository-h) this, but I haven't yet found a post that quite answers my question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to load the dump directly into the **repository, not a subfolder**. You have to specify the path to the repository, not the checked out working copy. Try this:

```
svnadmin create ./myNewRepo
svnadmin load ./myNewRepo < ./myOldRepo.svndump
```

This should do the trick..

Comment: I'm not using a locally-created repository. `myNewRepo` is hosted on assembla.com. What should I do to get the svndump into `myNewRepo`?

Comment: Aha, it looks like assembla.com has an in the web GUI.
More info: http://forum.assembla.com/forums/2/topics/2521-how-to-import-a-local-svn-repo

Comment: @solvingPuzzles, you can download a dump of your repository via the command `svnrdump`, provided that you have a recent enough svn. Take precautions regarding space, as svn repo dumps are usually quite large. (They get much smaller if you import them to git, if you want that).